# why apache poi reading less number of cell in a row of excel

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to fetch the cell using named range.But After trying the below code,not able to get consistent cell in a row of the sheet that's getting null exception while using `r.getCell()`.

```
String cname = "TestName";
Workbook wb = getMyWorkbook(); // retrieve workbook

// retrieve the named range
int namedCellIdx = wb.getNameIndex(cellName);
Name aNamedCell = wb.getNameAt(namedCellIdx);

// retrieve the cell at the named range and test its contents
AreaReference aref = new AreaReference(aNamedCell.getRefersToFormula());
CellReference[] crefs = aref.getAllReferencedCells();
for (int i = 0; i < crefs.length; i++) {
    Sheet s = wb.getSheet(crefs[i].getSheetName());
    Row r = sheet.getRow(crefs[i].getRow());
    Cell c = r.getCell(crefs[i].getCol());
    // extract the cell contents based on cell type etc.
}
```

Comment: A named range can include empty cells, so you need to check!

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of memory consuming, totally empty rows are not stored on the sheet. Also totally empty cells are not stored in rows of the sheet.

[Sheet.getRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow-int-) returns null if the row is not defined on the sheet. Also [Row.getCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell-int-) returns null if the cell is undefined in that row.

So we always need check:

```
...
Row r = sheet.getRow(crefs[i].getRow());
if (r == null) {
 //row is empty
} else {
 Cell c = r.getCell(crefs[i].getCol());
 if (c == null) {
  //cell is empty
 } else {
  //do something with c
 }
}
...
```